# Gstreamer rtsp server with different urls for payloaders

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp

I am working on streaming device with CSI camera input. I want to duplicate the incomming stream with tee and subsequently access each of these streams with different url using gst-rtsp-server. I can have only one consumer on my camera so it is impossible to have two standalone pipelines. Is this possible? See the pseudo pipeline below.

```
source -> tee name=t -> rtsp with url0 .t -> rtsp with url1
```

Thanks!

EDIT 1:

I tried the first solution with appsink | appsrc pair, but I was only half successful. Now I have two pipelines.

`nvv4l2camerasrc device=/dev/video0  ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=1920, height=1080, format=UYVY, framerate=50/1 ! nvvidconv name=conv ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=1280, height=720, format=NV12, framerate=50/1 ! nvv4l2h264enc control-rate=1  bitrate=10000000 preset-level=1 profile=0 disable-cabac=1 maxperf-enable=1 name=encoder insert-sps-pps=1 insert-vui=1 ! appsink name=appsink sync=false`

and

`appsrc name=appsrc format=3 is-live=true do-timestamp=true ! queue ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 name=pay0`

The second pipeline is used to create media factory. I push the buffers from appsink to appsrc in callback to new-sample signal like this.

```
static GstFlowReturn
on_new_sample_from_sink (GstElement * elt, void * data)
{
    GstSample *sample;
    GstFlowReturn ret = GST_FLOW_OK;
 

    /* get the sample from appsink */
    sample = gst_app_sink_pull_sample (GST_APP_SINK (elt));
    if(appsrc)
    {
      ret = gst_app_src_push_sample(GST_APP_SRC (appsrc), sample);
    }
  
    gst_sample_unref (sample);
 
    return ret;
}
```

This works - video is streamed and can be seen on different machine using gstreamer or vlc. The problem is latency. For some reason the latency is about 3s.
When I merge these two pipelines into one to create media factory directly withou usage of appsink and appsrc it works fine without large latency.

I think that for some reason the appsrc is queuing buffers until it starts pushing them to its source pad - On the debug output bellow you can see the number of queued bytes it stabilize itself on.

```
0:00:19.202295929  9724   0x7f680030f0 DEBUG                 appsrc gstappsrc.c:1819:gst_app_src_push_internal:<appsrc> queue filled (1113444 >= 200000)
0:00:19.202331834  9724   0x7f680030f0 DEBUG                 appsrc gstappsrc.c:1819:gst_app_src_push_internal:<appsrc> queue filled (1113444 >= 200000)
0:00:19.202353818  9724   0x7f680030f0 DEBUG                 appsrc gstappsrc.c:1863:gst_app_src_push_internal:<appsrc> queueing buffer 0x7f58039690
0:00:19.222150573  9724   0x7f680030f0 DEBUG                 appsrc gstappsrc.c:1819:gst_app_src_push_internal:<appsrc> queue filled (1141310 >= 200000)
0:00:19.222184302  9724   0x7f680030f0 DEBUG                 appsrc gstappsrc.c:1819:gst_app_src_push_internal:<appsrc> queue filled (1141310 >= 200000)
```

EDIT 2:

I add the max-buffers property to appsink and suggested properties to queues but it didn't helped at all.

I just don't understand how it can buffer so many buffers and why. If I run my test application with GST_DEBUG=appsrc:5 then I get output like this.

```
0:00:47.923713520 14035   0x7f68003850 DEBUG                 appsrc gstappsrc.c:1819:gst_app_src_push_internal:<appsrc> queue filled (2507045 >= 200000)
0:00:47.923757840 14035   0x7f68003850 DEBUG                 appsrc gstappsrc.c:1819:gst_app_src_push_internal:<appsrc> queue filled (2507045 >= 200000)
```

According to this debug output it is all queued in appsrc even if it has max-bytes property set to 200 000 bytes. Maybe I don't understand it correctly but It looks weird to me.

I tried the first solution with appsink | appsrc pair, but I was only half successful. Now I have two pipelines.

My pipelines are currently like this.

`nvv4l2camerasrc device=/dev/video0  ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=1920, height=1080, format=UYVY, framerate=50/1 ! queue max-size-buffers=3 leaky=downstream ! nvvidconv name=conv ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=1280, height=720, format=NV12, framerate=50/1 ! nvv4l2h264enc control-rate=1  bitrate=10000000 preset-level=1 profile=0 disable-cabac=1 maxperf-enable=1 name=encoder insert-sps-pps=1 insert-vui=1 ! appsink name=appsink sync=false max-buffers=3`

and

`appsrc name=appsrc format=3 stream-type=0 is-live=true do-timestamp=true blocksize=16384 max-bytes=200000 ! queue max-size-buffers=3 leaky=no ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 name=pay0`

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three possibilities:

1. Use appsink/appsrc ([as in this example](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/blob/master/examples/test-appsrc.c)) to separate the pipeline in something like:

   ```
                                  Factory with URL 1
       Capture pipeline      .---------------------------.
   .----------------------.  appsrc ! encoder ! rtph264pay 
   v4l2src ! ... ! appsink
                             appsrc ! encoder ! rtph264pay 
                             '---------------------------'
                                Factory with URL 2
   ```

You would manually take out buffers from the appsink and push them into the different appsrcs.

2. Build something like above, but use something like [interpipes](https://github.com/RidgeRun/gst-interpipe) or [intervideosink](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/inter/intervideosink.html?gi-language=c) in place of the appsink/appsrc to perform the buffer transfer automatically.
3. Use something like [GstRtspSink](https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/GstRtspSink_-_Dual_H264_Video_Streaming) (paid product though)

Comment: Thank you for answer. Please, see the edit I made.

Comment: I agree with your hypothesis. The appsrc is limited in size (which you can lower with the `max-bytes` property). However, the appsink is not limited and may queue a large amount of buffers. Try setting `max-buffers=3` or lower. Also recall that the nvv4l2camerasrc has an internal queue which may get filled, so I recommend adding a `queue max-size-buffers=3 leaky=downstream` right after the camera. Finally, limit the queue before the payloader by setting `queue max-size-buffers=3 leaky=no` (you can't drop encoded buffers).

Comment: I tried your suggestions but it didn't work. Please look at my edit.

Comment: Can you share your new pipeline?

Comment: I added it to my previous edit.

Comment: Actually, I just looked in appsrc sources and found that the max-bytes property is not limiting the size of queued bytes. It only emits enough-data when signal and stops pushing buffers if block property is set when reach the set limit.